# django with jwplayer cannot play Video

Tags: django, url, static, settings, jwplayer

I am writing a video Website which have a function of playing video ,i use the jwplayer as player, I have set the settings.py so that in my template(show_video.html) could get the Video path .the problem is: i keep getting 
Error Loading media:
File could not be played ,
but i open the html file directly ,it could play the VIDEO...
my video is a MP4 File 
Any help will be appropriate
Here is my settings.py clip:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     ('asset','/var/www/newproject/static'),
      # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
      # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
       #Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
 )

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/newproject/media'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX='/admin_media/'
```

And i have added a piece of code into the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',  
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^uploadFile$', 'pornsite.views.manage_video'),
  url(r'^playVideo/$','pornsite.views.show_video'),
  )

 urlpatterns += patterns('',(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Here is my templates(show_video.html):

```
<h1>mysite blog<h1>
        {% load static%}
{% block content %}
<h2>Video</h2>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/G7U50OC1EeKhaxIxOQulpA.js">
    </script>
<body>
        <div id='my-video'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer('my-video').setup({

            file: "{{MEDIA_URL}}lWMJeVvV-364767.mp4",
            image: 'http://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
            width: '640',
            height: '360'});
    </script>
</body>

        {{MEDIA_URL}}        
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my Apache default FILE CODE:
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  3     Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/wsgi/static/robots.txt
  4     Alias /favicon.ico /usr/local/wsgi/static/favicon.ico
  5     Alias /static/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/
  6     AliasMatch ^/([^/]*.css) /usr/local/wsgi/static/styles/$1
  7 
  8     #Alias /media/ /usr/local/wsgi/media/
  9     Alias /static/ /usr/local/wsgi/static/
 10     AddType text/html .py
 11 
 12     
 13         AllowOverride None
 14         Options None
 15         Order allow,deny
 16         Allow from all

Have anybody encounted this problem?

Try this code the jwplayer example:

```
<div id="container">jwplayer("container").setup({>
       flashplayer: "player.swf", 
       file: "http://streaming.openvideoads.org:81/shows/the-black-hole.mp4", 
       duration: 10,
       height: 300,
       width: 450,
       plugins: {
         "ova-jw": { 
             "regions": { 
                ...
             },
             "ads": {
                ...
             },
             "debug": { 
                ...
             }
         }
      }
});
</script>
```

Comment: i am totally got confuse by the ths django static file system, i need time to clear that tangle,

Comment: Could anyone help solve this question?

Comment: I have never used django before. Do you have an example of where you tried to run it?

Comment: I am writing a Video, A module of my website is when user upload the Video ,then convert it to the mp4 or flv format, when the convertion is done ,user Could view theri Video he(she) just uploaded, so my right now ,the jwplayer cannot play the Video ,but when opening the HTML file directly ,it can play.i guess that problem could be caused by the wrong path ,{{MEDIA_URL}} might not be configed correctly

Comment: by the way ,i am Chinese ,my english presentation is not very well.

Comment: Do you have a link I can look at, if possible?

Comment: I also have configed the STATICFILES_DIRS ,STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT the settings.py,But ii still cannot use the {% static "" %}expression to find my static file.

Comment: I am not sure what those are (i am not very familiar with django)

Comment: sorry , i have No Link,my project is just a development project, i am a Django Rookie , writing  a project as a practice. but i could send you my project source code , Do you have Facebook accout or some other file transfer software that i could send ?

Comment: I have never used django before. I just need to see some sort of example of the player being run so I can see what the error is, that's all.

Comment: I have solve this problem.i didn't map the /media/ to the MEDIA_ROOT in the Apache Server.

Comment: Great, glad you got it!